# MathJax bugged on front page (FireFox)

Tags: bug, mathjax, frontpage

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207572/the-laplace-transform-of-piecewise-function) question displays correctly when viewed in the /questions page:

[image]

But in the question queue, the preview is messed up:
[image]

My guess is that this is a result of cropping the MathJax markup halfway so that the preview stub becomes invalid MathJax. We can fix this simply by

- Removing the complete MathJax block if it would be cropped
- Cropping *after* the MathJax block

Note that the markup contains `$` inside the MathJax in this case. I will try to edit that away using `\begin{cases}` and report back.

---

After the edit it looks somewhat better, but still wrong:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This still occurs 2 1/2 years later. Either it wasn't fixed or the bug has resurfaced.

Example question: [Inequality involving gradients and Hessian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2553351/inequality-involving-gradients-and-hessian) - date December 5, 2017.

[image: Math Markup Error]

[Note: This is not intended to be a "comment answer" but a means to attach an image example of the problem, which due to the way this site's software is designed can not be uploaded to a comment (except by an offsite link which would then not display inline).]

Comment: Bugs that are fixed are usually tagged [meta-tag:status-completed].